# Pork rillettes - drain fat before shredding or not

Tags: pork, charcuterie

I'm about to start making some [rillettes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rillettes) with some pork belly and Lard left over from making scratchings the other day. I've looked at a few recipes but it's not clear if I should drain off the fat from the cooking before shredding the pork or not. I assume this would be the way to go so you can better control the amount of fat in the finished product.

Anyone know or have tried these themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... but it's not clear if I should drain off the fat from the cooking before shredding the pork or not. I assume this would be the way to go so you can better control the amount of fat in the finished product.

You are correct. Drain and reserve fat, shred the pork, re-add as much as you need.

Comment: (ta, hobodave.)